# What should I do about frequently repeated constants?

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns

This seems like a very simple question, but I can't find a clear answer. Also it's not specifically about swift or iOs, but I'm new to programming and swift is the only language I know anything about, so I don't know how to phrase it for a more general context.

I'm trying to write an iOs app and I found myself defining the same constants many times throughout my code.

I must have written this line about a hundred times, for instance:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
```

Another example is getting my only User object from its persistent store:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let user = realm.objects(User).first!
```

I define those `calendar` and `user` constants over and over throughout my whole code in classes and subclasses and extensions and computed properties.

That seems kind of stupid, though. I think I should be able to define `calendar` once and for all and just use it when I need it. So my first thought was to declare a global constant, but apparently everybody thinks anything with the word "global" in it should be avoided at all costs.

So what should I do? Is there another solution for this? Should I just keep writing the same stuff over and over again?

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

Comment: Good question, but not in the context of Stack Overflow. Let's talk about it at https://forums.developer.apple.com/community/xcode/swift

Comment: Alright then, I'll post it there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different situations in which the best use of different approaches.

For example in your case:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
```

`currentCalendar` is a static method that already returns a pointer to the object that you will use. And you don't need to set it to some constant for using with simple case:

```
print(NSCalendar.currentCalendar().calendarIdentifier)
```

Another thing that is most often better to use a shorter name for the object in your code when you need to refer to it often and this code looks much more readable:

```
print(calendar.calendarIdentifier)
```

If you have the functionality that you will often use in application from different places, you can just make it to the static method and does not create an object of this class every time you call it:

```
class NetworkConnection {
    class func getDataFromServet(completion block: (data: SomeType) -> Void) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And use it without object creation like:

```
NetworkConnection.getDataFromServer(completion: {(data: SomeType) -> Void in
    ...
})
```

If you need to use created object in many places, the best solution is not to make it global or singleton instance, but pass a pointer to it to the objects where you need to use it. This makes the code more readable, for example by looking at the input parameters of the `init` method, anyone can immediately understand which objects use this class for their work. And this class is easier to take from the project in a separate module and connect to another project. At that time, if you use the singleton instance, the class's interface is not clear what it can be used and this leads to code obfuscation. This applies and to the global objects.

Comment: Using a shorter name, like you mentioned in your example, is precisely what I want to do. So I don't get it, what should I do if I want to use `calendar` instead of `NSCalendar.currentCalendar()` everywhere?

Comment: `NSCalendar` is a standart Foundation class that have static method `currentCalendar` to return reference to calendar object. It's normal to use `let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()` in this case wherever you needed. It would be a bad decision to make a global reference to this object because you have in fact give this global link from `NSCalendar`. But in example with `Realm` you every time create new object and if you need to use one of them inside of many other objects the best decision will be pass a pointer to it (`Realm` object) to the `ini` of class where you need to use `Realm`

Comment: Uhm, ok, so for realm it's even more complicated than I thought. You mean I should override the `init` of view controllers and all?

Comment: Apparently calling Realm() doesn't create more than one object per thread, so that's not a problem. Still it would be nicer to call it once and be able to use it for every view controller. I didn't understand how that's possible from your answer.

Comment: @danielbmarques So that the thing that this is the wrong approach, you always want to have at hand the global object, which will be accessed from anywhere in the program, which leads to errors and code obfuscation, you should not do so

Comment: Oh, well, ok then. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score -1):

If you're constantly changing it, why aren't you just using `var` instead of `let`?

Comment: But I'm not changing it, I'm just using the same stuff over different files and classes and all sorts of places, so I have to declare it again.

Comment: Maybe add the code you're reusing into a separate file and import it into the files you need it in?

Comment: But that would be defining a global constant, wouldn't it? Isn't that a problem? People seem to be strongly against it.

Comment: I wouldn't consider that a global constant since it's not globally accessible. You have to import the file in order to be able to use it.